# spring-data mongodb POJO mappings in XML instead of annotation

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

Spring-Data provides Mapping annotation support for MongoDB. Annotations like @Id, @DBRef, @Field to help in mapping the objects to documents.

How do I provide the mapping information in XML instead of annotating the POJO.

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for XML mapping in Spring Data MongoDB. For simple scenarios you can just save your POJO without any mapping and it will be persisted in Mongo.

Take a look at [MongoTemplate save](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.3.3.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.html#save%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29) method Javadocs.

Comment: There are scenarios where we would like to externalize the mappings and do not want to annotate the POJOs with Mongo or JPA specific annotations. It would be better if we could externalize the persistence mapping and keep the POJO as a POJO in true sense.